# Would this be considered a break in the Title Chain?

Tags: contract-law, real-estate, homeownership, mississippi

I completed an application for a mortgage loan and was approved. My sibling and I both agreed to be listed on the Deed.

On the application: Borrower Information is just my name, The Title to the Property Will be Held in my name and Estate will be held in FEE SIMPLE. At closing a month later, I completed the closure disclosure. Almost the entire packet required just my signatures. The Non-Applicant Affidavit, and Name Affidavit were the only two documents my sibling was asked to sign. The Co-Borrower section was left blank in the entire packet. After Signing I was provided with a physical Warranty Deed that contained just my name. It has the original owner as Grantor and myself as Grantee. This record reflects in County Records now.

A Day later A Closure Disclosure Explanation generated stating:
Owner: My Name
Proposed Vesting: My Name & Sibling's Name

A week later after move in, we were asked to come back in to sign the Closure Disclosure again because the dates were wrong. In this packet, there were updated forms we signed that I did not notice until about 7 months later. One was a "NOTE" to be paired with a "Deed of Trust". I am the only one listed and signed on the Note, but both my sibling and I are listed as Grantor on the Deed of Trust and signed. I was never handed a physical copy after signing and was called to pick up another Warranty Deed Identical to the first one. The Deed of Trust record reflects in County Records with us both as Grantor and the Lender as Grantee now, and not once but twice.

With my sibling just "popping up" as a Grantor before being a Grantee, wouldn't this be a break in the Title Chain since there is no document or record of property actually being conveyed to them on the Chancery Clerk's Record?